# Exporting excel files from R in windows

Tags: r, xlsx

I'm trying to write excel files in R
When I'm tryin to access the package I'm getting this error message:

> library("xlsx")
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
> call: fun(libname, pkgname)
> error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

What does it mean?

Bare in mind I'm a noob

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than setting up Java, it might be eaiser to use a different package like [writexl](https://cran.r-project.org/package=writexl)

Comment: Also, you may use [readxl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html) package for importing/reading excel files.

Comment: Damn that was fast! Thanks guys will try both.